# Easy way to use between

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a rate table A

```
minDistance maxDistance Rate
1           100         x
101         200         x
......................
```

I have a table b that need look up price based on A

```
Distance Price
50        xx
500       xxx
```

I know how to write "between" query to look up the price, but it requires so many queries because we have many rows in A. Any easy way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean it requires so many queries? what queries have you tried that didn't work? what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN tableB b ON b.Distance BETWEEN a.minDistance AND a.maxDistance
```